# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration error in Eclipse Juno

Tags: maven, maven-3

Why does my Maven build work perfectly fine on the command line but when I run in Eclipse, it requires I add this section to my pom.xml,  otherwise I get this error:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration
: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile
 (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)
```

Isn't it strange that this occurs around the 'maven-compiler-plugin' plugin??  I cannot find another question like this anywhere on google, although I find many fix suggestions around 3rd party plugins.  I've done a great deal of researching and searching and found no explanation of this, not even [from here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered).

And the pom.xml required to fix this:

```
<!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e 
settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
        <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <versionRange>[3.1,)</versionRange>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <action> 
                        <ignore></ignore>
                    </action>
                </pluginExecution>
            </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And , [here is my simple project on GitHub](https://github.com/djangofan/maven-groovy) if you want to see my source.

Comment: maybe the m2e plugin is only supporting the compiler plugin version up to [2.0,3.0)?

Comment: I tried and it didn't help.  Basically , my project is a copy of the default archetype "gmaven-archetype" in the m2e archetype catalog.  Stangely, "out-of-the-box", it doesn't work and it throws this exact error I am reporting above.  Why can't someone make an archetype that actually works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally solved it.   It appears that the "pluginManagement" section I posted above is required by an Eclipse Maven project in general, even though I resisted it, and even though no documentation that I can find on the internet ever mentions this explicitly.

ALso, the "versionRange" in the lifecycle exclusion section seems to also require the version number of the "gmaven-plugin" rather than the "version of Maven" which I was trying to give it above.

```
<pluginExecutionFilter>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <versionRange>[1.5,)</versionRange>
    <goals>
        <goal>testCompile</goal>
        <goal>compile</goal>
    </goals>
</pluginExecutionFilter>
```

Comment: A pity the project is not longer on GitHub. Maybe the location is changed? Or in case it not longer exists, pls remove the link. Thx

Comment: So where does this go? Is this in the pom.xml of the maven plugin or in the pom.xml of the project using the maven plugin?

Answer (score 2):

1. Help -> Install new Software

   - Install the *Groovy Compiler 2.2 / 2.1 Feature*
   - Install *Groovy-Eclipse M2E integration*
2. Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Lifecycle Mappings -> Open workspace lifecycle mappings metadata

Add the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lifecycleMappingMetadata>
    <pluginExecutions>
        <pluginExecution>
            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                <versionRange>[1.3,)</versionRange>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                </goals>
            </pluginExecutionFilter>
            <action>
                <execute />
            </action>
        </pluginExecution>
    </pluginExecutions>
</lifecycleMappingMetadata>
```

3. Reload the Lifecycle Mappings and invoke a projekt update on your maven project. (ALT+F5)

Answer (score 2):

You may require an M2E "connector" to understand maven-compiler-plugin using the Eclipse (JDT) compiler.

Select "discover connectors" and choose M2E connector for Eclipse JDT compiler provided by JBoss, or install it manually.

> M2E connector for the Eclipse JDT Compiler    1.0.1.201209200903

You may also be offered a Groovy connector -- maybe it uses similar technology under the hood? -- but unless you are using Groovy, it probably does not make sense to install such integration.

Comment: Along with this , one also needs to update m2e version to latest one